# How to display validation error messages in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, ionic2

I want to create a form where the user will enter his First_Name and Last_Name. I'd like to validate those fields in client-side. 
Is there any generic forms validator in Angular 2 and also I want show the error message in client-side. How to show error messages ? 
Bellow is my code

html file

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm"  (ngSubmit)="submit()" >
<ion-row>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label primary floating>FIRST NAME</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" id="firstname" class="form-control" formControlName="firstname"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

 <ion-item>
   <ion-label primary floating>LAST NAME</ion-label>
   <ion-input type="text" id="lastname"  class="form-control" formControlName="lastname" ></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
</ion-row>
</form>
```

ts file:

```
this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
   'firstname'  :  ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(10)])],
   'lastname'   :  ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(10)])],})
```

Backend Endpoint name and fields name:

```
submit(){
    let registerNewUserObj ={
       first_name:this.myForm.value.firstname,
       last_name:this.myForm.value.lastname
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to display error messages.

```
<ion-input type="text" id="firstname" class="form-control" formControlName="firstname"></ion-input>
<p class="errorMessage" *ngIf="myForm.controls.firstname.errors && myForm.controls.firstname.dirty ">Please provide first name.</p>
```

Comment: Error showing  like Cannot read the property 'controls' in browser!

Comment: have you created like this in your component? myForm = new FormGroup({
      firstname: new FormControl(),
      lastname: new FormControl()})

Comment: @SelvaKumarDuraisamy I edited answer check it now. i was given addEntryForm instead myForm. now can you check

Comment: Now its displaying Form, but When i clicked the first_name and release there is no showing any error message!!

Comment: error shows "Cannot find control with name : firstname "

Comment: there is a mismatch in you formControlName and while displaying error. can you edit your question with new code?